# How to override remote backend with local backend in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have been looking at the terraform docs and a udemy course for the answer to this question, but cannot find the answer. I have a jenkins pipeline that is building AWS infrastructure with terraform. This is using a remote backend which is configured via a

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {}
}
```

block. I want to override this for local development so that a local state file is generated with `terraform init`. I have tried running `terraform init -backend=false` but I realize this is not what i want because it doesnt create a local backend either. I have seen `terraform init -backend=<file>` is an option, but if i use that then I dont know what to put in the file to indicate default local backend config. I found this article [override files](http://terraform.io/docs/configuration/override.html) but it doesnt lead me to believe that this functionality exists in terraform for this particular use case. I want to make sure I do this in the correct way. How does one override the remote backend config with a default local backend config in terraform? Thanks.

Comment: PS. The reason that I am doing this in the first place is so that I can run terraform against localstack to create AWS infrastructure.

Comment: Why not just remove the backend configuration block?

Comment: I can’t because that will break the terraform pipeline.

Comment: Your tests can remove it though right? So in the test job you just delete the file that contains the backend configuration or sed the block out of a larger file but don't push that change back up. Then your tests run against localstack with a local state file. Alternatively, why not use the S3 backend and stick the state file in localstack's S3 backend?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR are you saying in the test code, remove the backend file? I dont want to do it like that because it seems potentially problematic. Also we cant use the s3 bucket in localstack for the tfstate file because s3 is something in our AWS environment that is not managed with terraform.

Comment: I found this article. Is overriding files the best way to do this? https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/override.html

Answer (score 13):

The Terraform [override](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/files/override.html) concept you mentioned does work for this use case.

You can create files with an `_override.tf` added to the end elements of the override will take precedence over the original. e.g. `<my_existing_file>_override.tf`.

You can use this to override your existing backend config override the existing backend infrastructure so that you can init a local state file for testing/dev purposes.

I would create a config file with the following contents:

`backend_override.tf`:

```yaml
terraform {
  backend "local" {
    path = "./.local-state"
  }
}
```

Remember to add `*_override.tf` and `.local-state` to your .gitignore files so that you don't accidentally break your CI.