# Terraform Azure Resource Destroy

Tags: azure, terraform, github-actions, azure-storage-account

I have a simple terraform code that creates a storage account. When I plan and deploy it from my personal VM, it is fine and remains in sync.

When I then use GitHub actions and automate that process, the plan says in the first run that it will destroy the storage container and all child modules. The GitHub actions flow runs on a runner which is different from my own VM.

I have a thought that because it's a different machine, maybe that is why it wants to destroy the resource first but I am not sure. I don't want it to destroy. Is there a way to use terraform import to first import the resource there so that it doesn't destroy?

Can I somehow avoid this scenario? I can provide the files as well.

The solution works after adding the backend configuration as suggested by Marko in the comments.

main.tf :

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "resource-group"
    storage_account_name = "xxxxxxx"
    container_name       = "terraform-state"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  skip_provider_registration = true
}

# ############################ Storage Account ###########################
locals {
  storageAccount = fileexists("${var.storageAccountfilepath}/storageAccount.json") ? jsondecode(file("${var.storageAccountfilepath}/storageAccount.json")) : null
}

module "storageAccount" {
  for_each            = { for element in coalesce(local.storageAccount, []) : element.name => element }
  source              = "./storageAccount"
  storageAccountName  = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  filepath            = "${var.storageAccountfilepath}${each.value.name}"
}
```

storageAccount.tf

```
###############   Storage Account ##########################

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storageAccount" {
  name                = var.storageAccountName
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location =  var.location
  account_tier = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  table_encryption_key_type = "Account"
  queue_encryption_key_type = "Account"
  infrastructure_encryption_enabled = "false"
  tags = {
    env       = "sandbox-test"
    owner     = "som"
    CreatedBy = "soms"
  }

  blob_properties {
    change_feed_enabled = false
    container_delete_retention_policy {
      days = 7
    }
    delete_retention_policy {
      days = 7
    }
  }
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}
```

My github actions workflow

```
name: Terraform Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - develop
  # pull_request:
  #   branches:
  #   - main

# Special permissions required for OIDC authentication
permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read
  pull-requests: write

# These environment variables are used by the Terraform Azure provider to set up OIDC authentication.
env:
  TERRAFORM_PATH: './terraform'

jobs:
  terraform-plan:
    name: 'Terraform Plan'
    runs-on: [Windows,NonSOX]
    env:
      # This is needed since we are running Terraform with read-only permissions.
      ARM_SKIP_PROVIDER_REGISTRATION: true
    outputs:
      tfplanExitCode: ${{ steps.tf-plan.outputs.exitcode }}
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Setup Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
      with:
        terraform_wrapper: false
    - name: Get secrets from vault
      uses: hashicorp/vault-action@v2.7.0
      id: get_secrets
      with:
        exportToken: true
        method: jwt
        path: github-actions-oidc
        url: xxxxxxx
        role: actions-runner-finance
        tlsSkipVerify: true
        secrets: |
          /finance/data/terraform/AZURE_CLIENT_ID AZURE_CLIENT_ID | AZURE_CLIENT_ID ;                                       
          /finance/data/terraform/AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID | AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID ;
          /finance/data/terraform/AZURE_TENANT_ID AZURE_TENANT_ID | AZURE_TENANT_ID ;
          /finance/data/terraform/ARM_CLIENT_SECRET ARM_CLIENT_SECRET | ARM_CLIENT_SECRET ;

    - name: Terraform Init
      run: |
       pushd './${{ env.TERRAFORM_PATH }}'
       terraform init
     
    - name: Terraform Format
      run: |
       terraform fmt -check

    - name: Terraform Plan
      id: tf-plan
      env:
        ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ steps.get_secrets.outputs.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
        ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ steps.get_secrets.outputs.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
        ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ steps.get_secrets.outputs.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
        ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ steps.get_secrets.outputs.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET }}
      run: |
        pushd './${{ env.TERRAFORM_PATH }}'
        terraform plan -detailed-exitcode -no-color -out tfplan
        echo "exitcode=$LASTEXITCODE" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        
        if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 1) {
          echo "Terraform Plan Failed!"
          exit 1
        } else {
          exit 0
        }
```

Comment: You probably haven't configured a remote backend. Because of that, the state file on your machine is only where it exists, i.e., GitHub Actions know nothing about it. I would suggest defining a remote backend and rerunning everything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override remote backend with local backend in terraform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59775875/how-to-override-remote-backend-with-local-backend-in-terraform)

Comment: I tried using the backend config. set it up in a storage account in the resourcegroup, its initializing as well. the github actions step still says it will destroy all resources.  is it taking the local tfstate file, am not sure. I added these to the gitignore - 
*.local-state
*.tfstate
*.tfstate.*

Comment: Check  that the remote backend is correctly configured and initialized in both your local and GitHub Actions environments @Somsubhra Mukherjee

Comment: @MarkoE - Your idea worked, I had to re-work the entire thing from scratch. But its working now. Thank you

Comment: @SomsubhraMukherjee If the solution is resolved please post it as an answer it will be helpful to the other community people.

Answer (score 0):

The solution as suggested by Marko was to add the terraform backend configuration. Being a newbie, I missed that. I have added it to the original post as well in main.tf.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "resource-group"
    storage_account_name = "xxxxxxx"
    container_name       = "terraform-state"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```